# How do I use Semantic UI with ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I am building a web application, and I love the Semantic UI project, so I want to use it for my UI. The issue is that I am somewhat new to react.

The project is based off the [react-starter-kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit) application template, and I have previously learning the basics of React. I have researched integrating Semantic UI, and the official website states that no special bindings are required. At the moment, I am including the semantic files like traditional websites on every page, but I feel this is not the correct approach. I have researched react-semantic projects, but there seems to be no current stable version.

Is anyone using Semantic with React? What's the best practice?

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use it, if you just want the CSS/markup portion of it just include the CSS in your page and start using the classes. Remember to use `className` instead of `class`.

If you want to take advantage of the javascript (tabs, etc..) that's a bit trickier. It comes down to you wiring up your UI the react way, but also firing the appropriate Semantic functions.

Here's a react + jquery-bootstrap example. The implementation would be similar when using Semantic.

https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/master/examples/jquery-bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Hello @Rothschild Yes you can now integrate semantic ui easily. Check this respository https://github.com/kennethmervin01/react-with-semantic

It's a react boilerplate with semantic ui. You can integrate semantic with this simple script

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Segment, Button } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import '../semantic/dist/semantic.min.css'

const HelloWorld = () => (
    <Segment>
        <Button primary>Hello</Button>
        <Button secondary>World</Button>
    </Segment>
)

render(<HelloWorld />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the update ;) I'm happy to say I'm not so new to React any more